# excel clear sets format as accounting

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

In a specific workbook when i use `Clear > All` or `Clear > Formats` Excel sets the number format to **Accounting** instead of **General**.

This does not happen in other workbooks. It seems that Excel is using **Accounting** format as the "normal" format for this workbook.

Does anyone know if it possible to set the "normal" format for a workbook in Excel?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  This may have something to do with the original template the workbook was based on and may be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680465/how-to-change-the-default-number-format-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses the same principle of a normal style as Word does.

Hence to format the **Normal** style in Excel right click the style (in the Styles selection box) and click `Modify ...` then select `Format ...` and choose then in Number choose the format that best suits your needs.

Please see image bellow.

[Picture: Excel Modify cell format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgvvA.png)